# Converting XML date (ISO 8061) to Datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML column, that I'm extracting the datetime from:

```
SELECT PaymentXml.query('data(/PaymentSummary/SubmittedDate)') as 'ISO 8061 format'
```

But I want to get it into DateTime that I can work with in SQL Server.

Directly converting to datetime doesn't work

```
,convert(datetime,PaymentXml.query('data(/PaymentSummary/SubmittedDate)')) as 'VarChar Format'
```

> Explicit conversion from data type xml to datetime is not allowed.

I can convert it to varchar

```
convert(varchar(150),PaymentXml.query('data(/PaymentSummary/SubmittedDate)')) as 'VarChar Format'
```

But can't get that result to datetime.

```
,convert(datetime,convert(varchar(150),PaymentXml.query('data(/PaymentSummary/SubmittedDate)'))) as 'DateTime Format'
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Obviously I'm been working with XML in SQL Server for all of 30 minutes / don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: Posting an example of the strings you have in your column would be helpful. But a simple search on "sql server convert iso 8601 to datetime" will find many suggestions to get you started.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `datetime` try `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`.  ISO 8601 datetime precision exceeds the regular SQL Server `datetime` column type.

Comment: Wow, that was easy - datetime2

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should use `.value` to get a single XML value, not `.query`.

**You can use `CONVERT(datetime2` with style `127` to convert ISO-8061 dates:**

```sql
SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime2,
        PaymentXml.value('(/PaymentSummary/SubmittedDate/text())[1]','varchar(30)'),
        127) AS 'ISO 8061 format'
FROM YourTable
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0f51d8acdea50812bfdcafc38476fa55)